# Automatic variable, pointer after function still gets it

Tags: c, pointers, variables

compiling under Windows with gcc, from this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int ** iptr)
{
  printf("f initial value: %i\n",**iptr);
  int a =10;
  *iptr = &a;
  printf("f changed value: %i\n",**iptr);

  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  int * p = 0;
  int i =7;
  p = &i;

  printf("main initial value: %i\n",*p);

  f(&p);

  printf("main after f value under p: %i\n",*p);
  printf("again value under p: %i\n",*p);
  printf("value of i: %i\n",i);

  return 0;
}
```

I get this result:

```
main initial value: 7
f initial value: 7
f changed value: 10
main after f value under p: 10
again value under p: 1963422240
value of i: 7
```

Any idea, why this happens so?

Thanks!

P.S. And formatting of this website complains, that I did not write enough conversation here... So, being social... :)

Comment: That's [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in a nutshell. Besides that, the memory the pointer is pointing to doesn't physically disappear, it's just invalid to dereference it in any way.

Comment: Yes, but the first dereference still gets value 10, like it seems to survive the function call. I will have to check, if this is a matter of time. Like after longer time it will not show the correct value.

Comment: And yes, I placed a delay(100); function and this first dereference no longer showed 10. It is just about short timing.

Comment: Or, it is actually about stack being used by delay() function.

Comment: It's not a "matter of time", it's just plain *wrong*. Don't dereference pointers that are invalid.